# A spectacled person pulled on a rounded neck t-shirt and got stuck. Is there a word for that situation?

Tags: single-word-requests

Considering a situation wherin you regularly wear spectacles and have forgotten to take them off before wearing a round neck line(crew neck) T- Shirt and are now stuck because you've already slipped your arms in it.
 
In that moment, for a second you consider wearing it somehow but realising that you can't pull it through your neck, you're like, 'Oh! I'm ..........'  
If you've ever been in this situation, you'll know what I mean.

We can say 'stuck', but you can also get stuck if the T-shirt doesn't fit you due to many reasons. How to be more specific that you are stuck because of your spectacles. Is there a word or even a phrase for that?

EDIT:

Eventhough I've accepted an answer yet I'll be glad to receive and accept futher suggestions.

Comment: It's called "making a spectacle of oneself."

Comment: No word comes immediately to mind in relation to the specific situation of spectacles causing inconvenience during dressing. It may be more useful to describe particular emotions (exasperation?) or actions (flailing around?).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by ‘stuck’, nor why the shape of the t-shirt’s neck makes a difference. I've never had any trouble pulling a t-shirt over my head even when wearing (sun)glasses. The glasses may become a bit dislodged, but the t-shirt gets on just fine… Then again, I've never tried pulling a t-shirt _through_ my neck. That sounds painful.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think some of us have more problems like that depending on how our glasses fit. My partner's eyes are much more deeply set that mine which means the top edge of his glasses is almost tucked under his brow, while mine are more than 3cm proud of my face. I get in much more of a fankle with fleeces and t-shirts than he does.

Comment: You've reached an *eyewear knitwear impasse* :)

Comment: I would say "incompetent".  Most people who've been wearing glasses all their lives can pull on a t-shirt without getting their glasses hung up.

Comment: shirt-glass pickle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a specific word to describe this type of **apparel peril**.

The first word that came into mind was:

**[snagged](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&client=firefox-b&biw=1024&bih=584&q=snag%20meaning%20synonyms&oq=snag%20syn&gs_l=serp.1.1.0j0i22i30k1l3.0.0.1.11911.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0.5B-VfaYukLk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.140915558,d.cGc&ech=1&psi=5FNJWIiKBsjajwOc0ZiABw.1481200616527.3&ei=gVxJWK-MEYGymQG1pqnYAw&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&gfe_rd=cr)**

> 2) become caught on a projection

[also:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snag)

> to cause problems or difficulties for someone or something:

But while reading through the synonyms of snag, I came across

**[collar](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/snagged)** -- in the sense of *arrest*

So you might be able to say...

> "Yikes, I´ve been collared."

Comment: 'Collared' does have a nice ring to it. I'll use that. But what if it's a 'collar-less' one.:)

Answer (score 1):

You may perhaps say:

> 'Oh! I'm ***entangled***'

ODO:

> **[entangle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/entangle)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Cause to become twisted together with or caught in:
>   ‘fish attempt to swim through the mesh and become entangled’
>
> ‘When they hit bottom everyone was entangled with someone else's legs or arms.’

Comment: 'Entangled' is not what I'm looking for but +1 as it now made me coin a word 'spec-tangled'.